# textbox detect enter key after tab key selects autocomplete word

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textbox, keycode, autocompleteextender

I have an asp:TextBox with AutoCompleteExtender attached. This is my code

```
txtSearch.Attributes.Add("OnKeyPress", "ProcessKeyPressed()")

function ProcessKeyPressed()
  { 
    if(event.keyCode == 13)
      {
        Search()
      }
  }
```

The function Search() gets called when the user types in a word and presses enter.However, the enter key is not detected when the user hits the tab key to select one of the auto complete suggestions...Any ideas how I can fix this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code for

```
if(event.keyCode == 13 && e.keyCode == 9) //9 For Tab
{
   ....
}
```

LInk : http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes